# Comparing selected and preceding value in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am attempting to build a shiny app, that allows the user to select a time period via `selectInput` to then learn something about the chosen period. 
One of the things I'd like to implement is a simple comparison with the last period that preceded the selected one. I'd simply subtract the value of selected period t from the value of period t-1.

So far I have solved this with an additional `selectInput` to select period for the subtraction. 
Please consider this reproducible example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)

period <- factor(c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4"))
value <- 1:4

df <- data_frame(period, value)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("select1", "select quarter", choices  = unique(df$period)),
  selectInput("select2", "select preceeding quarter", choices  = unique(df$period)),
  verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "val")

)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$val <- renderText({
    (df %>% 
       filter(period == input$select1) %>% 
       select(2) %>% unlist()) - 
      (df %>% 
         filter(period == input$select2) %>% 
         select(2) %>% unlist())
  })

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I believe this to be a sub-optimal solution. Optimally, I'd like to use only 1 input and the app to automatically select the preceding value for the subtraction.

Is there a way to enable this functionality? I spontaneously thought of making use of the ordered nature of factor levels, but searching for this yielded no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can have a single `selectInput` in the `ui`, use `match` to find the index of the 'period' to `slice` the rows from the 'df' to get the `diff`erence of the 'value' with the preceding quarter

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("select1", "select quarter", choices  = unique(df$period)),
  verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "val")

)

server <- function(input, output) {


  v1 <- reactive({        

    i1 <- match(input$select1, df$period) # get the index
    i2 <- seq(pmax(1, i1-1), i1, by = 1) # create a sequence from the previous row

    df %>% 
      slice(i2) %>% #slice the rows
      pull(value) %>% # pull the value column
      diff %>% # get the difference of the two values
      .[1] #to make sure that we get NA if we select Q1

  })
  output$val <- renderText({
    v1()
  })

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

-output

[image]